# Conditions for a smooth curve

Tags: calculus, curves, parametric

A curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is considered to be smooth if its derivative, $\mathbf{r}'(t)$, is continuous and nonzero for all values of $t$. I have some concerns regarding the second condition:

Let's examine the curves $\mathbf{r}_1(t) = \langle t,t\rangle$ and $\mathbf{r}_2(t) = \langle t^3,t^3\rangle$. The former has a constant velocity, $\mathbf{r}_1'(t) = \langle 1,1\rangle$, while the latter has a varying velocity, $\langle 3t^2,3t^3 \rangle$, with $\textbf{r}_2(0) = \textbf{0}$. According to the definition, the curve traced by $\mathbf{r}_1$ is smooth, while the curve traced by $\mathbf{r}_2$ is not. However, both functions trace the same curve.

What might be causing my confusion here?

Comment: A curve is said to be smooth if it has no singular points, in other words if it has a (unique) tangent at all points.

Comment: A curve is a **function**, for example, $r:[a,b]\to \Bbb R^2$. It's a common misconception to confuse the function with its imagine, a **subset** of $\Bbb R^2$.